# Android send received data from a socket service to Activity

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, android-asynctask, android-handler

I am looking for a way to send received data (receive while flag is set) from a socket service to an activity that is bound to the service. What is the best way to do this ? Handlers , AsyncTask or something else ?

this is the SocketClass I am using to start a connection and handle the incoming messages :

```
    class connectSocket implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        running= true;
        try {
            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
            try {
                mBufferOut = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                mBufferIn = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                while(running){
                     msg = (Message) mBufferIn.readObject();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("TCP", "C: Error", e);
        }

    }

}
```

**Update :**

```
public class SocketService extends Service {
private static final String TAG = "com.oos.kiesa.chat";
public static final String SERVERIP = "192.168.X.X";
public static final int SERVERPORT = 4444;
private ObjectOutputStream mBufferOut;
private ObjectInputStream mBufferIn;
Socket socket;
InetAddress serverAddr;
boolean mRun;
Object msg;
public Integer command;
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return myBinder;
}

private final IBinder myBinder = new LocalBinder();

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    public SocketService getService() {
        return SocketService.this;

    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

public void IsBoundable(){
    Toast.makeText(this,"is boundable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


public void sendMessage(String message) throws IOException {
    if (mBufferOut != null) {
        mBufferOut.writeObject(message);
        mBufferOut.flush();
    }
}

public void sendMessage(Message message) throws IOException {
    if (mBufferOut != null) {
        mBufferOut.writeObject(message);
        mBufferOut.flush();
    }
}

public void sendMessage(User user) throws IOException {
    if (mBufferOut != null) {
        mBufferOut.writeObject(user);
        mBufferOut.flush();
    }
}

public void sendMessage(int command) throws IOException {
    if (mBufferOut != null) {
        mBufferOut.writeInt(command);
        mBufferOut.flush();
    }
}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flags, int startId){
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    System.out.println("I am in on start");
    Runnable connect = new connectSocket();
    new Thread(connect).start();
    return START_STICKY;
}

public void stopClient() throws IOException{

    if (mBufferOut != null) {
        mBufferOut.flush();
        mBufferOut.close();
    }

    mBufferIn = null;
    mBufferOut = null;
    socket.close();
}

class connectSocket implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        mRun = true;
        try {
            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
            try {
                mBufferOut = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                mBufferIn = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                while(mRun){
                    switch(command.intValue()){
                        case Constants.ADD_MESSAGE:
                            msg = (Message) mBufferIn.readObject(); // send message to Activity 
                            break;
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("TCP", "C: Error", e);
        }

    }

}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    try {
        socket.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    socket = null;
}
```

}

Some guidance / examples would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Why not using plain Java, i.e. define your callback Interface and implement it e.g. in  Singleton Sockethandlerimpl Class which you can access from anywhere.

Comment: I am doing a pretty basic chat app the received messages have to be displayed in a list view as soon as received. I though that I need to do it in a thread (handler inside the Activity )or something , and besides that  I don't have that much experience with java  as I would like to have .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sending you mine, hope it will help :

```
class SocketRequestHandler extends Thread {

    static String EOF = "<EOF>";

    TCPResponseModel tcpResponseDS;
    Activity activity;
    boolean doSkip = false;

    String responseStringComplete = "";
    Socket clientSocekt;
    OutputStream clientSocketOutputStream;
    PrintWriter clinetSocketPrintWriter;
    DataInputStream clientSocketInputStream;

    private SocketRequestHandler(TCPResponseModel tcpResponseDS, Activity activity, SaloonListener listener) {
        this.tcpResponseDS = tcpResponseDS;
        this.activity = activity;
        this.listener = listener;
        moreStores = tcpResponseDS.StoresFound;
    }

    public static SocketRequestHandler pingAll(Activity activity, TCPResponseModel tcpResponseDS, SaloonListener listener) {
        SocketRequestHandler requestHandler = new SocketRequestHandler(tcpResponseDS, activity, listener);
        requestHandler.start();
        return requestHandler;
    }

    private void closeStreams() {
        try {
            clientSocekt.close();
            clientSocketInputStream.close();
            clinetSocketPrintWriter.close();
            clientSocketOutputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            String pingingHost = "URL_TO_PING";
            clientSocekt = new Socket(pingingHost, 12000);
            clientSocketOutputStream = clientSocekt.getOutputStream();
            clinetSocketPrintWriter = new PrintWriter(clientSocketOutputStream);
            String firstPing = "{\"RequestId\":" + tcpResponseDS.RequestId + "}<EOF>";
            clinetSocketPrintWriter.println(firstPing);
            clinetSocketPrintWriter.flush();
            byte[] bytes;
            String pingStr = "";
            clientSocketInputStream = new DataInputStream(clientSocekt.getInputStream());
            while (true) {
                bytes = new byte[1024];
                clientSocketInputStream.read(bytes);
                bytes = trim(bytes);
                if (bytes.length > 0 && !doSkip) {
                    String newString = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
                    String decoded = pingStr + newString;
                    pingStr = checkForMessage(decoded);
                    responseStringComplete += newString;
                }
                if (doSkip) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            closeStreams();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            System.out.print(responseStringComplete);
        }
    }


}
```

To broadcast chat data just do :

```
msg = (Message) mBufferIn.readObject(); // Do code after this line                            
 Intent localIntent = new Intent("CHAT_MESSAGE");
 localIntent.putExtra("message", msg);
```

LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(localIntent);

Now in the activity where you are showing the chat list you can do

```
class ReceiveMessages extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            if (action.equals("CHAT_MESSAGE")) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        String chatMessage = getIntent().getStringExtra("message");
                        //get data from intent and update your chat list.
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
    ReceiveMessages myReceiver;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //your code
        myReceiver = new ReceiveMessages();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(myReceiver,
                new IntentFilter("CHAT_MESSAGE"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
    }
```

Comment: Hey there , thank you for sharing your code. I am trying to do a simple chat app , my service is running while the TCP connection is Open and so I can get data at any time in any Activity , I just don't really get how to display for example a message send from the server in my listview (ChatActivity)

Comment: If your server is able to handle socket connection, then this is the best and fastest thing you can do. You just need to Run this code on a continuous running service who will open the Client socket and communicate. Now using local broadcast just broadcast your all data getting from server. Now you can just put your receiver in any hosting activity  and you will be able to get the chat data easily.

Comment: I updated my Question , included the whole service class. I am pretty sure I am missing something important I just dont know what. I am searching for days my brains about to explode. Can you look into it ?

Comment: I didn't understand, why you are using a new thread, Service itself runs on a  different thread then you can do all on the same same thread. If Your code is working fine then just broadcast your data what you are getting from server, so any active activity that is meant to shwo the chat will receive and show in your chat list (Updating my post for code ).
Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Thank you for your help I will try this out right away. One last question  I am receiving different type of Objects for example : User.class Object Message Object and some other stuff will localIntent.putExtra("message", msg);  put the actual object and pass it to the activity (cast it back to the object in activity) ?

Comment: Whatever object you are getting just make that class parcelable, and write that object directly to the intent. 
localIntent.putExtra("obj", object);
and to read it again in receiver do this
MyModel object = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("obj");

Comment: where do I get the context from ? the context you used in your code is not defined ,  sorry to keep bothering you .

Comment: I did not get your problem exactly, because first code belongs to service and second part belongs to Activity, and at both places Context is always available by getApplicationContext().

Comment: the classes I get from the server are Serializable  wouldn't I get exceptions if I make them parcelable and on the server they  would still be  Serializable  ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114564/discussion-between-neo-and-kiesa).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AsyncHttpClient {

public AsyncHttpClient() {

}

public static class SocketIORequest {

    private String mUri;
    private String mEndpoint;
    private List<BasicNameValuePair> mHeaders;

    public SocketIORequest(String uri) {
        this(uri, null);
    }

    public SocketIORequest(String uri, String endpoint) {
        this(uri, endpoint, null);
    }

    public SocketIORequest(String uri, String endpoint, List<BasicNameValuePair> headers) {
        mUri = Uri.parse(uri).buildUpon().encodedPath("/socket.io/1/").build().toString();
        mEndpoint = endpoint;
        mHeaders = headers;
    }

    public String getUri() {
        return mUri;
    }

    public String getEndpoint() {
        return mEndpoint;
    }

    public List<BasicNameValuePair> getHeaders() {
        return mHeaders;
    }
}

public static interface StringCallback {
    public void onCompleted(final Exception e, String result);
}

public static interface WebSocketConnectCallback {
    public void onCompleted(Exception ex, WebSocketClient webSocket);
}

public void executeString(final SocketIORequest socketIORequest, final StringCallback stringCallback) {

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            AndroidHttpClient httpClient = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("android-websockets-2.0");
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(socketIORequest.getUri());
            addHeadersToRequest(post, socketIORequest.getHeaders());

            try {
                HttpResponse res = httpClient.execute(post);
                String responseString = readToEnd(res.getEntity().getContent());

                if (stringCallback != null) {
                    stringCallback.onCompleted(null, responseString);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {

                if (stringCallback != null) {
                    stringCallback.onCompleted(e, null);
                }
            } finally {
                httpClient.close();
                httpClient = null;
            }
            return null;
        }

        private void addHeadersToRequest(HttpRequest request, List<BasicNameValuePair> headers) {
            if (headers != null) {
                Iterator<BasicNameValuePair> it = headers.iterator();
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    BasicNameValuePair header = it.next();
                    request.addHeader(header.getName(), header.getValue());
                }
            }
        }
    }.execute();
}

private byte[] readToEndAsArray(InputStream input) throws IOException {
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(input);
    byte[] stuff = new byte[1024];
    ByteArrayOutputStream buff = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int read = 0;
    while ((read = dis.read(stuff)) != -1) {
        buff.write(stuff, 0, read);
    }

    return buff.toByteArray();
}

private String readToEnd(InputStream input) throws IOException {
    return new String(readToEndAsArray(input));
}
```

Comment: Use this socket client